# Traversing a string backward in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, traversal

Suppose I have a string "ABCD"

What's the easiest way I can define a method to print out

D 
C
B
A

?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like homework. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: With or without the spaces between letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 > "ABCD".reverse
=> "DCBA"
```

Ref: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/String.html#method-i-reverse

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define a new method:

```
puts "ABCD".reverse
```

If you need it with spaces between the letters you can try:

```
"ABCD".each_char.to_a.reverse.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

`print myString.reverse`